# Scissor Function in iphone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image

Hiii Everyone i m developing a Photo Collage App in iPhone and i want to use scissor functionality in my app so any one have idea how to get this fun. in my app and if anyone know about any open Source API to provide Scissor functionality.....

Comment: You have to be much more detailed on what you want and what have you already tried. Also try to show some research effort on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in this [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html) In short, use this function, it makes cropped image from uncropped image and cropping mask.

```
CGImageRef CGImageCreateWithMask (
   CGImageRef image,
   CGImageRef mask
);
```

Comment: Thank Oner TpaxMaH for sending reply on my question but can u give some more Clue about This one because i m new in iPhone technology and i want some  more clue on this topic and can u have any link for example of this functionality

Comment: Start with reading guide I give; when you finish, ask any specific question.